# Offering more bounty than reputation score?

Tags: support, bounty

I come across this question where I found the user offered more bounty than the amount of reputation that he had:

[SQLSRV Query Returning Output Parameter As Strange Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300405/sqlsrv-query-returning-output-parameter-as-strange-text)

I am wondering how it is possible for any user to offer bounty on their question worth more than their reputation?

If this is possible, how does a user giving the correct answer get those bounty points, since the user offering the bounty itself didn't have enough reputation?

Comment: The 50 was removed when the bounty was set. It is not removed at the end of the bounty, but at the beginning.

Comment: I don't underatnd that why people are downvoting these type of questions

Answer (score 11):

When the OP posted the bounty, he had 79 reps. Lost 50 bounty points and then gained 20 points from upvote, so now he has 49 reps.

As soon as you post a bounty, points are deducted from your reps right away.

> **What happens when I place a bounty?**
>
> The reputation you're using for the bounty is immediately and irreversibly deducted from your reputation.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: But then why it is still showing as open bounty from this user ? And also if bounty already awarded, then there should be any answer marked with that points i guess . isnt it ?

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee Bounty has been started but not awarded, it is still open. When you start bounty, reps are deducted from you. When you award the bounty, reps are given to the other user.

Answer (score 8):

This reputation is *after* OP has offered the bounty, see their [reputation activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4213742/polaris?tab=reputation):

[image]

Before OP set the bounty, they had >50 rep.

Comment: But then why it is still showing as open bounty from this user ? And also if bounty already awarded, then there should be any answer marked with that points i guess . isnt it ?

Comment: @CodeWithCoffee Not necessarily. See [Set Bounties privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)